# Fastest way to perform shapely "difference" function on two different dataframes?

Tags: python, gis, geospatial, geopandas

I have a two geodataframes : one is a multipolygon with geometry of the city, and the other with all the buildings in the city. I wanted to subtract all the building footprints from the total area in the city to get the remaining area. For this, i use a for loop for each building geometry, and subtract the building area from the multipolygon. I get correct results, but the simulation takes way too long (since the there are about 17000 buildings present). My question is there a faster way to perform this operation?

```
buildings = gi_osm_geo.overpass_result_to_geodataframe(
        gi_osm_geo.query_overpass_types_in_area(
            region_or_tags=area_tags,
            search_tags=[("building", "")],
            link_by_or=True,
            relations=True,
            ways=True,
            nodes=False,
        )
    )

    in_crs = buildings.crs
    if in_crs is None:
        in_crs = "EPSG:4326"  # If no crs is set, assume EPSG:4326
        buildings = buildings.set_crs(in_crs)
    utm = buildings.estimate_utm_crs()
    buildings = buildings.to_crs(utm)
    buildings["area"] = buildings["geometry"].area
    buffered_geo = buildings.geometry.buffer(buffer_in_m)
    buildings = buildings[buildings["geometry"].is_valid]
    build = buildings.head(100)
    merged = buffered_geo.cascaded_union
    for building in buildings["geometry"]:
            merged = merged.difference(building)
```

Comment: Can you include sample data for `merged` and `buildings`?

Comment: What is the purpose of the result?